# Easy way to Git squash?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I often do this:

```
git add -u
git commit
```

*...discover mistake, fix it...*

```
git add -u
git commit -m "Fix typo"
```

Is there an easy way to squash the second commit back into the first? Sometimes I can do it with `git rebase -i`, but sometimes I just get a message about being up to date.

Note I'm only really talking about situations where I haven't pushed the first commit. Basically I want to use the first log message, but with the combined effect of the two commits. Can I use `git commit --amend` for such things?

This related question kind of dealt with this:
[git: squash/fixup earlier commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204461/git-squash-fixup-earlier-commit)

The best answer is a year old though, and I wonder if things have improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what `git commit --amend` is for. Given your example, all you need to do is add the `--amend` flag to your second commit:

```
git add -u
git commit
```

...discover mistake, fix it...

```
git add -u
git commit --amend
```

You can do this visually in `git gui` also (there is a radio-box to toggle between "new commit" and "amend last commit")

Comment: Interesting - didn't know about `git gui`. I wonder why there's both that and gitk. (Competing for the ugly prize? :p )

Comment: These two have different purposes: `git gui` is for commiting, and `gitk` is for viewing and managing branches. Note that you can start `git gui` from `gitk` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is this article that talks about the autosquash feature introduced in git 1.7.

http://technosorcery.net/blog/2010/02/07/fun-with-the-upcoming-1-7-release-of-git-rebase---interactive---autosquash/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just amend the previous commit.

```
git add typointhisfile
git commit -vm
```

OR if you've already created 2 commits - you can make them one with:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Just squash one of them into the other.

You're better off (IMO) though, preventing the problem in the first place. And for that I suggest always doing verbose commits:

```
git commit -v
```

Before writing the commit message - skim the diff of the changes you are going to commit, and just close your editor if you see something you need to correct. Closing without entering a commit message will abort the commit.

Make it a habit and the need to commit typo-corrections will all but disappear.

Comment: Yeah. I actually do lots of visual checks (git diff --cached, in particular). Still easy to miss stuff. And of course, you're *supposed* to commit often. So it doesn't make sense to hold off committing until everything is perfect...

Comment: committing often and committing mistakes are 2 different things @SteveBennett